# Solution to this differential equation that does not diverge at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation

$$\tan x \; \frac{\text{d} y}{\text{d} x} + y = {\rm e}^x \tan x$$

By using the integrating factor $\mu(x)=\cos{x}$, I solved it as an equation in full differentials and got the solution (verified with WolframAlpha).

$$y(x) = A\csc{x} + \frac{1}{2}{\rm e}^x(1-\cot{x})$$

However, the question I am solving asks for a solution that does not diverge at $x=0$, which this solution clearly does because of the $\cot{x}$. How can I get a solution that converges?

Comment: You need to adjust $A$ for that. Try an expansion

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks, I've worked it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $$A\csc(x)+\frac12\mathrm{e}^x(1-\cot(x))=\frac{A}{\sin(x)}+\frac{\mathrm{e}^x}2\left(\frac{\sin(x)-\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}\right)$$ $$=\frac{A+\frac{\mathrm{e}^x(\sin(x)-\cos(x))}2}{\sin(x)}.$$ Notice that the divergence at $0$ occurs because $\sin(0)=0.$ Consider the numerator, $$A+\frac{\mathrm{e}^x(\sin(x)-\cos(x))}2.$$ At $0,$ this numerator is equal to $A-\frac12.$ This leaves you with the only option $A=\frac12,$ to ensure the singularity at $0$ becomes removable.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @ClaudeLeibovici:

At $x=0$, we want $A\csc{x} = \frac{1}{2}{\rm e}^x \cot{x}$. By representing $\csc{x}$ and $\cot{x}$ in their complex exponential form, and substituting $x=0$, we get $A=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).